# Positioning a chart

Tags: excel, vba

My code, to plot a chart from data in sheet1 and place the chart in a specified location of sheet2 gets interrupted in positioning commands:

```
.Left = Range("B2").Left
.Top = Range("B2").Top
```

with the Compile error:

> Compile error: Method or data member not found

Can anyone help me to find the cause?

```
Sub addchrt()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim objChrt As ChartObject
    Dim chrt As Chart
    Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A20,C2:C20")

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2")
    With ws
        .Shapes.AddChart
        Set objChrt = .ChartObjects(.ChartObjects.Count)
        Set chrt = objChrt.Chart
        With chrt
            .ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
            .SetSourceData Source:=rng
            .HasTitle = True
            .ChartTitle.Text = "Test"
            .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
            .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "xxx"
            .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
            .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "yyyy"
            .HasLegend = False
            .Left = Range("B2").Left
            .Top = Range("B2").Top
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Well, First off you have an additional `End With` at the end. Second `.Left` and `.Top` are not properties that a Chart has. So that's why its giving that error. Edit: I see that ChartObject does have these properties. So it should be  `objChrt.Left` and `objChrt.Top`. Do those work?

Comment: Thanks. I just removed the additional `End With` , your suggestions also work. I wonder why it did not work that way. I already defined chart as `objChrt.Chart` before 'with'.

Comment: You can also set them as arguments in the `AddChart` method at the start.

Comment: Well, objChrt.Chart returns a `Chart` object. and objChrt itself is a `ChartObject` object. And because you used `With chrt`, `.Left` tries to refer to `chrt.Left` which doesn't exist. While `objChrt.Left` does exist.

Comment: @erazorv4 Thanks.

Comment: @Rory. Thanks. does it also take range as input?

Comment: Per the help, it takes chart type, left, top, height and width arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your unedited code. There was an extra `End With` that was causing a problem

---

Your trying to access the `.Left` and `.Top` property of a [Chart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.chart%28object%29) object. Which doesn't exist.

However, the [ChartObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.chartobject) object that you have does have a `.Left` and a `.Top` property. So those should be used like so

```
        objChrt.Left = Range("B2").Left
        objChrt.Top = Range("B2").Top
```

You can also set the position of the Chart when making it, like Rory mentions in his comment,

documentation on that can be seen [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shapes.addchart2). (Note that I couldn't find this exact method for excel, there is one similar listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.shapes.addchart))